# Implement Word freeze functionality in HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, ms-word

As I am a beginner in designing and have not much idea about CSS manipulating so need some help.

I have one HTML page and want to implement the same functionality of freeze as we are using in Word.

Here I am having the table and want to freeze the first 4 columns so it doesn't move and stay sticky and the last column to show the total and only allow in between columns to move with scrolling bar.

[image]

NOTE: The table is dynamic and rows and columns will be dynamic. Here is my code `[https://jsfiddle.net/padhiyarmahavirsinh/b51k20sr/3/][2]`

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to make two tables, give one a fixed height and add a scroll bar. You're gonna have to tweak it for your site

```js
//not part of styling, just to get the total
const total = document.querySelector("table:last-of-type tr td:last-child");
const money = document.querySelectorAll("table:first-of-type tr td:last-child");
let sum = 0;

money.forEach(({
  innerText
}) => {
  sum += parseInt(innerText);
});

total.innerText = sum;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 125px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table:first-of-type {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>money</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>7923</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>7981</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>3724</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>4234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>12939</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>3247</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>5798</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>5324</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>total</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```